# why it's slowly when I parse a message of Google protocol buffer in multi-thread?

Tags: multithreading, protocol-buffers

I try to parse many Google protocol buffer messages from a binary file generated by calling SerializeToString. I first load all Bytes into a heap memory by calling new function. I also have two arrays to store the Bytes begin address of a message in the heap memory and the Bytes count of the message. 
Then I begin to parse message by calling ParseFromString.I want to quicken the procedure by using multi-thread.
In each thread, I pass the start index and end index of address array and Byte count array.

In parent process. the main code is:

```
struct ParsePara
{
    char* str_buffer;
    size_t* buffer_offset;
    size_t* binary_string_length_array;
    size_t start_idx;
    size_t end_idx;
    Flight_Ticket_Info* ticket_info_buffer_array;
};

//Flight_Ticket_Info is class of message
//offset_size is the count of message
ticket_array = new Flight_Ticket_Info[offset_size];
const int max_thread_count = 6;
pthread_t pthread_id_vec[max_thread_count];

CTimer thread_cost;
thread_cost.start();

vector<ParsePara*> para_vec;
const size_t each_count = ceil(float(offset_size) / max_thread_count);
for (size_t k = 0;k < max_thread_count;k++)
{   
    size_t start_idx = each_count * k;
    size_t end_idx = each_count * (k+1);

    if (start_idx >= offset_size)
        break;

    if (end_idx >= offset_size)
        end_idx = offset_size;

    ParsePara* cand_para_ptr = new ParsePara();

    if (!cand_para_ptr)
    {   
        _ERROR_EXIT(0,"[Malloc memory fail.]");
    }   

    cand_para_ptr->str_buffer = m_valdata;//heap memory for storing Bytes of message
    cand_para_ptr->buffer_offset = offset_array;//begin address of each message
    cand_para_ptr->start_idx = start_idx;
    cand_para_ptr->end_idx = end_idx;
    cand_para_ptr->ticket_info_buffer_array = ticket_array;//array to store message
    cand_para_ptr->binary_string_length_array = binary_length_array;//Bytes count of each message

    para_vec.push_back(cand_para_ptr);
}   

for(size_t k = 0 ;k < para_vec.size();k++)
{
    int ret = pthread_create(&pthread_id_vec[k],NULL,parserFlightTicketForMultiThread,para_vec[k]);

    if (0 != ret)
    {
        _ERROR_EXIT(0,"[Error] [create thread fail]");
    }
}

for (size_t k = 0;k < para_vec.size();k++)
{
    pthread_join(pthread_id_vec[k],NULL);
}
```

In each thread the thread function is:

```
    void* parserFlightTicketForMultiThread(void* void_para_ptr)
{
    ParsePara* para_ptr = (ParsePara*) void_para_ptr;

    parserFlightTicketForMany(para_ptr->str_buffer,para_ptr->ticket_info_buffer_array,para_ptr->buffer_offset,
            para_ptr->start_idx,para_ptr->end_idx,para_ptr->binary_string_length_array);
}

void parserFlightTicketForMany(const char* str_buffer,Flight_Ticket_Info* ticket_info_buffer_array,
        size_t* buffer_offset,const size_t start_idx,const size_t end_idx,size_t* binary_string_length_array)
{
    printf("start_idx:%d,end_idx:%d\n",start_idx,end_idx);
    for (size_t k = start_idx;k < end_idx;k++)
    {
        if (k % 100000 == 0)
            cout << k << endl;

        size_t cand_offset = buffer_offset[k];
        size_t binary_length = binary_string_length_array[k];
    ticket_info_buffer_array[k].ParseFromString(string(&str_buffer[cand_offset],binary_length-1));
    }
    printf("done %ld %ld\n",start_idx,end_idx);
}
```

But multi-thread cost is more than one thread.
one thread cost is:40455623ms
My computer is 8 core and six thread cost is:131586865ms

Anyone can help me? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Some possible problems -- you'll have to experiment to determine which:

- Protobuf parsing speed is often limited by memory bandwidth rather than CPU time, especially with a large input data set. In that case, more threads won't help, since all the cores are sharing bandwidth to main memory. Indeed, having multiple cores fighting over memory bandwidth could make the overall operation slower. Note that the biggest consumer of memory is not the input bytes but rather the *parsed* data objects -- that is, the *output* of parsing -- which are many times larger than the encoded data. To improve this problem, consider writing the parsing loop so that it fully-processes each message immediately after parsing, before moving on to the text message. That way, instead of allocating k protobuf objects, you only need to allocate one protobuf object per thread, and repeatedly reuse the same object for parsing. This way the object will (probably) stay in the core's private L1 cache and avoid consuming memory bandwidth; only the input bytes will be read over the main bus.
- How are you loading data into RAM? Did you `read()` into a large array or did you `mmap()`? In the latter case the data is read from disk lazily -- it won't happen until you actually attempt to parse it. Even in the `read()` case, it could be that the data has been swapped out, creating similar effects. Either way, your threads are now not just fighting for memory bandwidth, but *disk* bandwidth, which is of course *much* slower. Having six threads reading separate parts of a big file will definitely be slower overall than having one thread read the whole file, because the operating system optimizes for sequential access.
- Protobuf allocates memory during parsing. Many memory allocators take a lock while allocating new memory. Since all your threads are allocating tons and tons of objects in a tight loop, they will contend for this lock. Make sure you are using a thread-friendly memory allocator, such as Google's tcmalloc. Note that repeatedly reusing the same protobuf object in a parse-consume loop rather than allocating lots of different objects will also help immensely here, because the protobuf object will automatically reuse memory for sub-objects.
- There may be a bug in your code and it might not be doing what you expect at all when multithreaded. For example, a bug might be causing all the threads to process the same data, rather than different data, and it could be that the data they're choosing happens to be bigger. Make sure you are testing that the results of your code are exactly the same when you run single-threaded vs. multi-threaded.

In short, if you want multiple cores to make your code faster, you have to think about not just what each core is doing, but what data is going in and out of each core, and how much the cores have to talk to each other. Ideally you want each core to operate all on its own without talking to anyone or anything; then you get maximum parallelism. That's not usually possible, of course, but the closer you can get to that, the better.

BTW, a random optimization for you:

```
ParseFromString(string(&str_buffer[cand_offset],binary_length-1))
```

Replace that with:

```
ParseFromArray(&str_buffer[cand_offset],binary_length-1)
```

Creating at `std::string` makes a copy of the data, which wastes time (and memory bandwidth). (This doesn't explain why threading is slow, though.)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I'll experiment to determine the reasons for the problem. Thanks again.